# Extract columns of a string using grep

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need to extract from `/proc/net/dev` the second and tenth columns separated by spaces. In other words, the number of received and transmitted bytes.

Is it possible to do this using `grep` and back-references?

Comment: is sed mandatory ? awk is more suited for that kind of work.`awk '{print $2,$10}' dev`

Comment: I need exactly the regular expression for grep. I believe that its possible but dont know how.

Comment: For sed the following expression works s/( *[^ ]*)( *[^ ]*)( *[^ ]*){7}( *[^ ]*).*/\2\4/. But for egrep it does not work

Comment: `grep` is the tool to print the lines that match a regex, (that's where the name comes from), not to extract data from the lines (though some implementations now have a `-o` option that can do it to some  extent).

Answer (score 1):

to answer you question:

```
awk '{print $2,$10}' /proc/net/dev
```

yield

```
Receive
|bytes packets
6385384218 42314607745
12034420041 12034420041
```

which might not be what you are after.

you can use

```
awk '$1 ~ /:/ {print $2,$10}' dev
6385389751 42314610935
12034420241 12034420241
```

where

- `$1 ~ /:/` select line where first filed is foo:
- `{print $2,$10}` print second and tenth field

## grep

1. grep can be use to match a regular expression, so you can pick numbers from `/proc/dev/net`
2. however, regular expression describe but cannot act.

In other word, I see no regular expression applied to **a single grep command** then will turn

```
  eth0: 6385654376 26986310    0 107680    0     0          0      4665 42314947519 21475282    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 12034424441 4553238    0    0    0     0          0         0 12034424441 4553238    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

to (not exact figure)

```
6385389751 42314610935
12034420241 12034420241
```

using `grep FOO`

where `FOO` consist only of grep's options and arguments.

In @Emeric's try he could have two columns, when i run on my OS:

```
6385672702
42314983073
12034425441
12034425441
```

yet, you can try your luck at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Archemar nailed it in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If all you can use is `grep`, have a go at the following:

```
grep -Eo '[^ ]+:( *[0-9]*){9}' /proc/net/dev | grep -Eo '(: *[0-9]*|[0-9]*$)' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
137517672
9029195
```

- First expression prints the interface name + colon, followed by the next 9 groups of digits.
- Second expression extracts only the groups of digits preceded by the colon or followed by the end of line (First and last selected columns). This is where the line is split into one line per matching column.
- Last expression gets rid of the leading colon (*Nothing political here*).

As pointed out earlier, `grep` is far from being the best way to achieve this.

Comment: That do not answer OP's question, see my edit.

Comment: Good point. I missed the 'seprated by spaces' part.